# Deploy jar file in IBM Liberty Batch Server

Tags: java, batch-processing, websphere-liberty

What are all the artifacts (Jar, war or ear) that can be deployed in a Liberty Batch Server. I a currently running standalone jar file (triggered from a shell script). As per the standards established in my Organization, I have to move this to IBM Liberty Batch server. Do I need to convert this jar to war file to deploy or I can directly run the jar file in Liberty Batch server. If I run the jar in batch server container, how do I trigger the batch from my shell script? or i don't have to use shell script for triggering?

Comment: Where are the API docs for the jar, is there a web URL for the version?  And does the jar require to start with a main method or is it add on , just classes?

Comment: It a jar file required to start with a main method. Want to retain as such so that i dont have to make code changes.

Comment: If your organisation is standardised on using Liberty Batch Server, surely one of your colleagues can help?

Comment: Do you want to run multiple jobs per JVM instance (per server start) or just a single job (after which the JVM can exit)?

Comment: Single job. Want to trigger the job from a shell script and the scheduler we have will invoke the shell script

Answer (score 3):

Your script can use the batchManager command line utility (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=liberty-batchmanager-command-line-client-utility) to submit the job to the Liberty server indicated in the parameters you supply to the CLI.  The parameters also include the application name (leading to the .war file, so yes, .war, not .jar) and the name of the JSL file within it.  If you're on z/OS, there is also a batchManagerZos utility that does the same thing, but without requiring a userid/password since you're already authenticated to z/OS.  You could also directly use the REST interface which batchManager is driving under the covers (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=liberty-batch-rest-api).

Comment: The Liberty Admin Center UI can also be used to view and manage java batch jobs:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=center-viewing-java-batch-jobs-in-admin